# Http error connecting to the WAMP server

Tags: php, android

I am getting this error when I am trying a make a httppost call from my Android app to WAMP server for log in validation. I am using android phone for the debugging

NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(10430): (thUse=67032) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.

Any suggestion please......

Comment: Have you enabled the `android.permission.INTERNET` in your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Yes I did but still giving me that error

Comment: You should provide more LogCat log since this has not much to do with your connection issue.

Comment: NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(13230): (thUse=67208) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()                                                               KeeperManager(13230): (thUse=67208) INITIALIZATION of shared resourcesAndroidContextProviderImpl(13230): (thUse=67208)    currentActivityThread=nullNafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(13230): (thUse=67208)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(13230): (thUse=67208)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.